# C++ banking project, vector of structs.

Tags: c++, vector, struct

i am working on a project to create a database of bank accounts. So i have to use a vector of structs. So here in my header file there is the struct and also the function prototype for a method to makeAccount().

```
struct Account{ 
int accountNumber;
string lastName;
string firstName;
double accountBalance;
};

//function prototype
template <typename typeStruct>
void makeAccount(vector <typeStruct>&);


//makeAccount method
void makeAccount(vector<T>&v)
{
    T newacc;
    newacc.accountNumber=rand()%9000+1000;
    cout<<"Creating bank account number "<<newacc.accountNumber<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter first name: ";
    cin>>fname;
    newacc.firstName=fname;
    cout<<"Enter last name: ";
    cin>>lname;
    newacc.lastName=lname;
    cout<<"Enter starting balance: ";
    cin>>principal;
    newacc.accountBalance=principal;

}
```

My implemented method is supposed to create a new account every time it is called and ask for first name, last name, and starting balance with a random acc number being generated. Right now Im having trouble figuring out how to call by reference to the function as well as to add the inputted values to the vector of structs. Im a beginner so any explanations would be great, thank you.

Comment: Why are you using a template if you're going to access specific member variables anyway?

Comment: i thought it was odd as well, but the instructions clearly state that a template was necessary.

Comment: If you are going to do it this way, you need another `template` clause: `template <typename T> void makeAccount(vector<T>&v) { ... }`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Your code is a good start though - well done.

Comment: so essentially- in my main I declare a vector of type account called bankAccounts. Then i try to call the method makeAccount(bankAccounts), it throws an error saying undefined reference to makeAccount, im having trouble understanding what exactly im passing to the function. I think im passing a reference of the vector bankAccounts, but then im stuck as to what to do with that vector. How do i manipulate add another struct element to my vector and modify its member variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that makeAccount is supposed to add to the referenced vector and you do not know how. If so, the answer is simple, simply go with `v.push_back(newacc);` at the end of your function (it's not a method, by the way, methods are within some class).

v is a reference, which means that everything that happens to v inside makeAccount happens to the variable that you gave to makeAccount, just as you want. push_back is the usual method for vector to add an entry.

Btw, makeAccount has no idea what T is, you have to put `template<typename T>` in front.

In your main, it would look like this

```
int main(){

    vector<Account> accounts;

    while(some_condition){

        makeAccount(accounts);
        do_something_that_changes_condition;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

As for the error you talk about in the comments, give us your main.

That said, your question is somewhat hard to understand, if this is not what you wanted to know, I'll edit this.

Comment: yes thats what im asking, but say i want to add another bank account with a different name, accnum, etc... If i call this function again, then will it simply append to the end of 'v' in this case.

Comment: @zrendy Yes, it will. That's what push_back does. And since v is always located at the address at which accounts is located - that's the idea of a reference - everything is okay.

Comment: So how do i go about and access say, element at index 5 of this vector and print out the information i need?

Comment: @zrendy std::cout << accounts[5].firstName << std::endl; for example, although I'd define a method print in Account for that and then go with accounts[5].print();. You might want to look at this example I just coded: http://cpp.sh/6hpya

Comment: @zrendy Another thing, coding it this way is somewhat unorthodox. I don't see why you use a reference instead of either making makeAccount to return an Account, like `Account makeAccount();` and then call it by `accounts.push_back(makeAccount());` or making it a method of Account, like `struct Account{... Account()}; Account::Account(){accountNumber=rand()%9000+1000; ...}` and then call it by `accounts.push_back(Account);` or if this should not be the standard constructor, going with something like  `struct Account{... static Account read_account()};`

Comment: @zrendy Or even creating a class Accounts that wraps such a vector and has makeAccount() as a method.

Comment: i found it confusing as well, but the instructions state most of this. I still dont understand why a template is necessary if the only struct we are working with is Account.